# Analytical Solution of Non-Linear Coupled ODE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fluid-dynamics

I have the following coupled PDE, which describes the trajectory of a non-inertial particle in [Taylor-Green Vortex Flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%E2%80%93Green_vortex):
$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \begin{bmatrix} x_p \\ y_p \end{bmatrix} = e^{-2 \nu t} \cos \left( \beta \begin{bmatrix} x_p \\ y_p \end{bmatrix} \right) \sin \left( \beta \begin{bmatrix} y_p \\ - x_p\end{bmatrix} \right)$$
Assuming some initial condition $x_p(0), y_p(0)$, is it possible to obtain an analytical solution for $x_p(t)$, $y_p(t)$?

I've tried to manipulate this equation with trigonometric identities but was not able to find a simpler form. Additionally, I attempted to change coordinates such that it could be described in terms of polar coordinates with respect to the nearest vortex, (anywhere where the value of $e^{-2 \nu t} \sqrt{\cos^2(\beta x_p) \sin^2 (\beta y_p) - \cos^2(\beta y_p) \sin^2(\beta x_p)} = 0$), but did not find anything productive.

Comment: (1) You have a system of ODEs, not PDEs, as there is a single independent variable. (2) What do you mean by the cosine (and sine) of a vector?

Comment: Assuming the vectors in the sine and cosine are just representing the terms in each ODE, you have a conserved quantity $\cos (\beta x_{p}) \cos (\beta y_{p}) = C$ which can be used to determine $x_{p} = f(y_{p})$.

Comment: @Gonçalo, I was just trying to simplify it into one equation. The velocity vector at any point is:
$$ \vec{u} = e^{-2 \nu t} \Big \langle \cos(\beta x) \sin(\beta y), - \sin(\beta x) \cos(\beta y) \Big \rangle $$

Comment: If you define new variables $u = x+y$ and $v = x-y$, the system simplifies a little.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{dt}=e^{-2\nu t}\cos(\beta x)\sin(\beta y) \\
\frac{dy}{dt}=e^{-2\nu t}\cos(\beta y)\sin(-\beta x)  
\end{cases}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{e^{-2\nu t}\cos(\beta y)\sin(-\beta x)}{e^{-2\nu t}\cos(\beta x)\sin(\beta y)}=-\frac{\sin(\beta x)\cos(\beta y)}{\cos(\beta x)\sin(\beta y)} =-\frac{\tan(\beta x)}{\tan(\beta y)}$$
$$\tan(\beta y)dy=-\tan(\beta x)dx$$
$$-\frac1b \ln(\cos(\beta y))=\frac1b \ln(\cos(\beta x))+\text{constant}$$
$$\cos(\beta y)=c\:\cos(\beta x)$$
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{\beta}\cos^{-1}\big(c\:\cos(\beta x)\big)$$
This is the equation of the trajectory of the point $\big((x(t),y(t)\big)$.

In order to find $x(t)$ one put $\quad \sin(\beta y)=\pm\sqrt{1-c^2\cos^2(\beta x)}\quad$ into the firsrt ODE.
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm e^{-2\nu t}\cos(\beta x)\sqrt{1-c^2\cos^2(\beta x)}$$
This first order ODE is separable :
$$\pm\int e^{-2\nu t}dt=\int \frac{dx}{\cos(\beta x)\sqrt{1-c^2\cos^2(\beta x)}}$$
This gives $t(x)$ and then the inverse function $x(t)$. One can do it with the help of WolframAlpha.

The same to find $y(t)$.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me.. yes. Continuing from JJacquelin's equation

$$~\frac {\cos \beta y }{\cos \beta x} =c, $$

If we let  $\beta x = \psi(t),~ \beta y = \phi(t), $ then we can see that the trajectories can be further split up as hyperbolic asymptotic geodesics.

They obey separable but *coupled* Sine-Gordon equations on a pseudosphere of another *arbitrary Gauss curvature* $\dfrac{-1}{a^2}.$

$$ 2 a^2  \psi^{''} =\sin  2 \psi~;$$

$$ 2 c^2 a^2 \phi^{''} =\sin  2 \phi~;$$

The Odes are primed on time $t$. Their solutions are well known.

I suppose this special free? vortex motion arises from non-Euclidean hyperbolic geometry as hyperbolic geodesics.